# pgf-pie: How can I put the percentage values in the legend?

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts, pgf-pie

In the pie chart below, how can I move the percentage numbers out of the chart, and put them in the legend on the right, with the names? I'm using the [`pgf-pie`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie?lang=en) package.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\centering
\pie [text = legend] {25.75/Transformator , 12.59/aaaaaa,11.18/aaaaa,9.91/HV aaaaa,
9.10/aaaaaC, 7.99/aaaaa,7.47/aaa,5.74/aaaaaa4.95/aaaaa,4.19/aaaa680uf,1.06/aaaaaa} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{pie chart.}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SE! Please upgrade your code snipped so, that we can copy and compile!

Comment: For the similarly flummoxed, [pgf-pie](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf-pie).

Comment: sorry but i don't understand the explanation :/ how can i "Open up (make a copy/backup) the pgf-pie.sty file and scroll to the end, there is a part enclosed in \iflegend … \fi. Replace the enclosed scope environment with""